# Gmail API retrieves emails, but doesn't have their content

Tags: python, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I'm working on a simple email digest script for myself using the Gmail API, but I've run into an issue where only some emails are processed correctly. For example, suppose I have 3 emails. I will be able to retrieve the body contents of the first, but the other 2 say that they don't have any content when they very much do.

```
78      for mail in emails:
79          # extract body of email                                                                                                                                 
80          content = msgs.get(userId = 'me', id = mail['id'], format =
81      "full").execute()['payload']
82          print()
83          print(content["body"])
84          print()
```

where `emails = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q = query).execute()['messages']` and q is just the filter  `query = "label:unwanted-for-digest"`

The output looks something like this:

```
{'size': 0}

{'size': 44866, 'data':'PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw-DQo8aHRtbCBsYW5nPSJlbiI-DQo8aGVhZD4NCjx0aXRsZT50.........

{'size': 0}
```

I can read the data from the second email, but not from the rest. This confuses me because when I print out the output of content["headers"], I get proof that these emails do exist.

```
6 Algorithms Every Developer Should Know | Richard Warepam in Dare To Be Better noreply@medium.com Fri, 01 Jul 2022 14:30:00 +0000 (UTC)

The ONLY sustainable sale: Up to 60% off + free shipping thredUP <reply@smart-shopping.thredup.com> Fri, 1 Jul 2022 02:44:06 -0700

What makes senior software engineers laugh when they look at a junior engineer's code?  Fri, 01 Jul 2022 02:01:31 +0000
```

What's the cause for this discrepancy?

Comment: Can it be related to the message having different content type, like one been plain text, and the other HTML format/multipart?

Comment: Could you review if the emails not showing content are HTML or plain text?

Comment: @GiselleValladares They all seem to be HTML...suppose they weren't, though. Would their contents be located somewhere else, then?

Comment: It might be. 

I tested using `format = "raw"` instead and imported "Base64" to decode, and it works for me. If you are interested, I can give you the sample code I was using. 

When I was using raw, I noticed that the payload was divided into 2 parts, 1 with the plain text and one with the HTML. I guess it can be the same with `format = "full"`. 

However, I have never used `format = "full"` so I'm not sure.

Comment: @GiselleValladares Actually you're right; it turns out that the ones that were missing were multipart. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the payload of the code, we noticed that the structure was a [multipart/digest container](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.get_content_type:%7E:text=multipart/digest%20container), so the information list was stored in a different part.